# Select TOP 0 and OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a piece of code that seems very difficult for me to comprehend tho I have a brief understanding how both Select TOP 0 and Outer APPLY work separetely.
What does this code do?
Thanks is advance!

````
select * from taxex t1
   outer apply 
         (select top 0 id, b_date, total_sum from loans t2 where t1.id = t2.id 
                                               and t1.i_date >= t2.b_date) ```
````

Comment: In theory that outer apply does absolutely nothing and would probably be ignored by the optimizer - you could test this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibly useful action of the `outer apply` in question is the null values in columns generated by the `outer apply` are casted to the type of respective columns of the `loan` table. Compare:

The query below will fail with

> Msg 241 Level 16 State 1 Line 1 Conversion failed when converting date
> and/or time from character string.

```
select  t1.*, t2.*
from (
   select 1 a, 2 b
) t1
outer apply (
  select top 0 cast('2002-01-01' as date) d
) t2

union all 
select 3, 4, 'abc';
```

While the next one is ok

```
select  t1.*, null d
from (
   select 1 a, 2 b
) t1

union all 

select 3, 4, 'abc'
```